# .Net Core on Linux request to Exchange Web Service returned 401 Unauthorized

Tags: c#, linux, .net-core, exchangewebservices

I have .net core 2.0 console application that connect to EWS:

```
var service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2007_SP1)
{
    Credentials = new WebCredentials("username", "password", "domain"),
    Url = "https://domain/ews/exchange.asmx",
};
var view = new FolderView(10);
var r = _service.FindFolders(new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Contacts), view);
r.Wait();
```

On windows its working good. If application running on Ubuntu, then exception: "Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceRequestException: The request failed. The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized."
The server responds with a header: "WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate, NTLM". 
I did not find anything about NTLM in Net Core on Linux and trying connect to EWS through cntlm (Cntlm is an NTLM/NTLMv2 authenticating HTTP proxy) proxy.

```
service.WebProxy = new System.Net.WebProxy("http://localhost:3120/"),
```

Error remains.

How can I fix that?

Comment: First, test against .NET Core on Windows.

Comment: On windows it's working good.

Comment: We opened an issue for this: https://github.com/sherlock1982/ews-managed-api/issues/14